# Примеры галлицизмов синтаксиса в русском языке

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, стилистика

В Википедии говорится, что "[Наряду с лексическими галлицизмами для русской литературы типичны галлицизмы синтаксиса, то есть синтаксические конструкции, перенятые из французского языка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC#:%7E:text=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D1%81%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B8%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0.).", но примеров там не приводится. Может ли кто-нибудь их дать?